# How to add new text field when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to create a form for my client. My client require to create a dynamic for him.
Suppose, I want to insert 1 record in main table of mysql, and record multiple records in secondary table which has reference key of main table. I don't know how many records against the main table, it maybe one at time or multiple records at time. I want to do it with single form. If client click add more button it show another text field to insert more data.
how I can do it ?????

Answer (score 6):

```
It would be possible using pure javascript
```

like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()"/>

<span id="responce"></span>
<script>
var countBox =1;
var boxName = 0;
function addInput()
{
     var boxName="textBox"+countBox; 
document.getElementById('responce').innerHTML+='<br/><input type="text" id="'+boxName+'" value="'+boxName+'" "  /><br/>';
     countBox += 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. You give me the idea that how can i do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible through the jquery/javascript.

So you can use this reference :http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Just try it!!

Answer (score 2):

here is the code:

```
    function generateTextBox()
    {

     var mainDiv=document.getElementById('options');
     alert(mainDiv);
     var newBreak=document.createElement('br');
      mainDiv.appendChild(newBreak);
    for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
      {

     var newTextBox=document.createElement('input');
     var newBreak1=document.createElement('br');
     var newBreak2=document.createElement('br');
     var newBreak3=document.createElement('br');
     var text = document.createTextNode("Option"+i);


     newTextBox.type='text';

     newTextBox.setAttribute('id','txtAddr'+i);
         alert(newTextBox+"2");
        mainDiv.appendChild(text);
     mainDiv.appendChild(newTextBox);
     mainDiv.appendChild(newBreak1);
     mainDiv.appendChild(newBreak2);
     mainDiv.appendChild(newBreak3);


     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to write my own code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't php related, you'll need to dynamically add to the form using javascript.